# Jms Serializer dynamic exposure

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, serialization

I am using Symfony 3, Doctrine 2, FOS Rest bundle and JMS Serializer.
I am using the exclude all policy across my app and then selectively exposing fields.

On the User Entity, I want to be able to expose additional fields only for the current user.

For example on the normal `api/user/{id}` endpoint, I want to expose the normal data, but then for `api/user/current` I want to expose slightly more data.

Eg.

```
/**
* ...
* @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Serializer\Expose
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secretfield", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $secretfield;
```

I have tried the `@groups` decorator, but that only works to further whittle down the fields and would require me changing loads and being careful to set the "default" group context everywhere.

I have seen the [Dynamic Exclusion Strategy](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy), mentioned in [the docs](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy), but I can't figure out if it is what I need or not and which variables are available to build an expression out of.

Any ideas what the best way to do this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main worry was the "send everything by default" behaviour that would come from setting the exclusion policy to none.

But I looked into the groups a bit more and found that I could set a default group in the config.

```
fos_rest:
  serializer:
    groups: ["default"]
```

I tested this on my User controller and without specifying any groups on the entity or in the Serializer context, it returned nothing.
So I modified my entity to use `@Serializer\Groups({"default"})` instead of `@Serializer\Expose`. Which brought me back to the same returned data as when I started.

I then added the `current_user` group to the secret fields of my entity and added the group to the serializer context to get those additional fields for that particular view.

In the entity:

```
/**
* ...
* @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("none")
*/
class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Serializer\Groups({"default"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @Serializer\Groups({"current_user"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secretfield", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $secretfield;
```

And in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("user/current")
 *
 * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
 */
public function getCurrentAction()
{
    $me = $this->getUser();

    $view = new View($me, Response::HTTP_OK);
    /** @var Context $context */
    $context = $view->getContext();
    $context->setGroups(['current_user', 'default']);
    $view->setContext($context);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: If you set a global group like this, then you have to specify the group in every single entity class and on every property that you want to be shown, so it is not ideal. Using expose, you could make certain entities expose none by default and specify the ones to expose, but other files could just expose all. but with this method you are forced to annotate every property in an entity that you just want to return all.